# Individually modulate two lasers diodes using sound - while using the same power suppy and preventing signal "bleed over"

Tags: audio, circuit-design, laser, signal-integrity, laser-diode

I'm trying to individually modulate two lasers diodes using the same power supply.  **The modulation for each laser module is created by the left and right audio channels.**  Is there a way to do this using one power supply? Here's a little circuit idea I came up with but I notice that the left and right channels (signals) may "bleed over" into each other is there a way to prevent this "bleed over" so each laser is modulated by just one of the audio channels but still have the ability to use the same power supply?

See circuit idea along with website I got it from
[image: Circuit idea]

Website I got the idea from http://scitoys.com/laser_communicator.html

Comment: Why use audio transformers? Id go with a simple dual opamp audio amp.

Comment: You've placed the two laser diodes in series. You need to completely replicate the original schematic twice except for the battery. Connect the single battery to both circuits exactly the way it's connected in the original.

Comment: @AdilMalik I'm following the website instructions just doubling it
http://scitoys.com/laser_communicator.html

Comment: @DoxyLover I'm not sure what you mean I did replicate the original. I have two transformers and two lasers and 1 battery, and I only have one battery connected to both circuits.  I use the Potentiometer to limit the voltage

Comment: You have the two laser diodes connected cathode-to-cathode - that won't work.  The battery negative should go to the laser diode cathodes. The common wire between the transformer primaries should go to the jack sleeve, not to the switch contact.

Comment: Use two pots. Connect the battery plus to each pot and the battery minus to each transformer. Each laser connects to its own pot and transformer. This way, you have two completely separate current loops from the battery. The way you did it, you have one current path through everything.

Comment: Note: " lasers being sold lately that have no protection, and need the bicolor LED to absorb any extra high voltage the transformer may produce when it is connected or disconnected."

Comment: @PeterBennett Sorry I got those switched around I'm following http://scitoys.com/laser_communicator.html and I'm trying to replace the box symbols they use with correct ones.

Comment: The audio step up transformer can exceed the -5V breakdown voltage and they fail abruptly.

Comment: Use a dual op-amp to create buffered copies of the left and right signals. There are too many variables with audio source impedance and different audio levels, etc. Maybe you can use transconductance amplifiers (TCA's).

Comment: @mkeith  I'm very interested in the op-amp method do you know of any examples?

Comment: @AdilMalik  I'm very interested in the op-amp method do you know of any examples?

Comment: Do you have any idea how much current you want to go through the laser diode?

Comment: @mkeith I plan on using these diodes <5mw https://www.amazon.com/Laser-Diode-Module-650nm-10pcs/dp/B00R73MC1S/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1445359889&sr=8-1&keywords=laser+diode